# Подскажите пожалуйста, КАК сделать загрузку img в laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

Подскажите пожалуйста, КАК сделать загрузку img  в laravel 5.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Добавить Route**

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('image-upload','ImageController@imageUpload');
Route::post('image-upload','ImageController@imageUploadPost');
```

**2. Добавить controller**

app/Http/Controllers/ImageController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class ImageController extends Controller
{

    /**
    * Create view file
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function imageUpload()
    {
        return view('image-upload');
    }

    /**
    * Manage Post Request
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function imageUploadPost(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);

        $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);

        return back()
            ->with('success','Image Uploaded successfully.')
            ->with('path',$imageName);
    }

}
```

**3. Создать файл Blade**

resources/views/image-upload.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Laravel 5.3 Image Upload with Validation example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading"><h2>Laravel 5.3 Image Upload with Validation example</h2></div>
  <div class="panel-body">

        @if (count($errors) > 0)
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        @endif

        @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </div>
        <img src="/images/{{ Session::get('path') }}">
        @endif

        <form action="{{ url('image-upload') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="file" name="image" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

  </div>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Примерно так.

Comment: спасибо огромное, сейчас буду пробовать, увидел многие моменты, которых мне нехватало)очень грамотно написано,уже и с исключениями...